# Ejecutar un storeprocedure en php5.6

Tags: php, stored-procedure, plsql, php5, sql-server-2014

tengo un store procedure que funciona y me trae el id de la sucursal y la sucursal a la que pertenece X usuario que ingresa por un login
Mi store procedure se mira así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez que el storeprocedure ya me trae lo que quiero, lo quiero pintar en la web que estoy haciendo en php así mi codigo:

```
<?php
require('menu.php');

require('conexion.php');
$consulta="EXEC SPAccesoMSphp '$username' , '$password', '11'"; 
$resultado=sqlsrv_query($consulta,$conn); 
while($rows=sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado)){ 
echo "Id: ".$rows[0]."<br>"; 
echo "Sucursal".$rows[1]."<br>"; 
} 


?>
```

Pero no me funciona, solo me manda estos erores, no se si este mandando a llamar bien el storeprocedure, de ante mano gracias

> Notice: Undefined variable: username in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MIDAS\index.php on line 31
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: password in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MIDAS\index.php on line 31
>
> Warning: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\MIDAS\index.php on line 32
>
> Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\MIDAS\index.php on line 33

Answer (score 0):

Pero es verdad no estas declarando las variables $username y $password, lo que entiendo es que esas variables las obtienes del login, pero las tienes que capturar en algun lado por ejemplo al momento de validar el login esos datos los envias a un php de validacion y ahi los obtienes:
$username=POST['usuario']; 
$password=POST['password']; 
lo mismo debes hacer en tu php por eso te envia ese error "Undefined variable"